# Responsive UI tools for automation testing with C# selenium

Tags: selenium2

We are moving our applications to responsive UI [C#]. Please suggest how best to use automated testing tools [Selenium] on a responsive UI.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you looking for UI testing tools?

Answer (score -2):

I would personally consider each breakpoint a unique site within selenium.

You can set the window size using something similar to the following;

In either your base class or at the top set the various sizes you wish to test (that way if they change you need only update one place)

```
Dimension expectedWindowSizeMobile = new Dimension(600, 500);
Dimension expectedWindowSizeTablet = new Dimension(1024, 768);
Dimension expectedWindowSizeDesktop = new Dimension(1288, 988);
```

Then within your individual tests set it appropriately for example,

Test 1

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(expectedWindowSizeTablet)
driver.findElement(By.id("TabletMainImage")).isDisplayed()
```

Test 2

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(expectedWindowSizeMobile)
driver.findElement(By.id("MobileMainImage")).isDisplayed()
```

So you can have a set of tests run at each size point checking for the presence of the appropriate elements.

Comment: How is this an answer ?The OP's question is directed towards suggesting tools and not towards an specific issue with code.

Comment: its a means of accomplishing the task via selenium (the tool suggested in the question).  You already added a comment on the question saying you are "not sure what you're asking" so how can you also say my response is wrong?